# A new ExFAT partition prevents bootcamp from starting windows

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition

I'm trying to create a shared partition that I can use from both Windows and OS X. I made a new partition, but if I make it FAT or ExFAT Windows does not start. I get Error code: 0xc000000e. I assume this is because it tries to boot from the empty partition instead of the bootcamp partition.

If I make the partition use Apple's filesystem, I can boot to Windows again but then the partition becomes read-only.

Any suggestions how to solve this? All partitions are on the same hard drive - I don't have any external drives. I created my Bootcamp installation using Yosemite and later updated. Today I used El Capitan to create the new shared partition. It is a MacBook Pro from mid 2014 and I run Windows 10.

Output from *diskutil list*

```
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            69.7 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Shared                  99.4 GB    disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                80.8 GB    disk0s5
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +69.4 GB    disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 6AA15FCB-EEFC-4182-8382-EC890574DBDA
                                 Unencrypted
```

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac? What version of windows do you have installed? It is also important where you created the new partition with respect to the OS X and Windows partitions. Can you edit your question and add the output from the Terminal command `diskutil list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this

I used the Disk Management tool in Windows to delete the shared partition and then created a new partition with NTFS file system.